# Unable to find cacheable object with identifier - id - in cache

Tags: ios, sirikit

I'm trying to implement INCreateNoteIntent for Siri in my app.
Siri resolves all the needed content, she goes through confirm, and through handle intent method, and it all works, but the final response from Siri is:

*Sorry, there was a problem with the app*,

What was printed in the console log is this:

`[Intents] -[INCache cacheableObjectForIdentifier:] Unable to find cacheable object with identifier 5BCBE5F9-5DD6-4E63-AF5C-F3863BF56ECD in cache.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having this exact same problem when using the `INCreateTaskListIntent`. Maybe you're having a similar problem with the `INCreateNoteIntent`?

It turns out that on the final response that you create in the `handle` method, you have to assign a new a `INTaskList` object to the response or else it's not a valid successful response (that is, successful responses must have the `createdTaskList` field set). Perhaps your note problem is similar?

Here's an example of my code before and after the fix:

Before (I'm not creating and setting the task list):

```
func handle(intent: INCreateTaskListIntent, completion: @escaping (INCreateTaskListIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    guard let title = intent.title else {
        completion(INCreateTaskListIntentResponse(code: .failure, userActivity: nil))
        return
    }

    print("Creating task list called \(title)")
    let response = INCreateTaskListIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil)
    completion(response)
}
```

After (I set the task list):

```
func handle(intent: INCreateTaskListIntent, completion: @escaping (INCreateTaskListIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    guard let title = intent.title else {
        completion(INCreateTaskListIntentResponse(code: .failure, userActivity: nil))
        return
    }

    print("Creating task list called \(title)")
    let taskList = INTaskList(
        title: title,
        tasks: [],
        groupName: nil,
        createdDateComponents: nil,
        modifiedDateComponents: nil,
        identifier: "superduperlist"
    )
    let response = INCreateTaskListIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil)
    response.createdTaskList = taskList
    completion(response)
}
```

Comment: Shocking how the documentation does not mention this anywhere, nor is 'createdTaskList' a required property. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem apparently you need to add a App Groups key type array to your .entitlements file with an item of type string with an custom id of yours

[Image of .entitlements file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9jLs.png)

Comment: i have keys added in entitlements file. Still i am not able to receive data in continueUserActivity method. i am trying with ride intent extension. Should i post a separate question ?

Comment: i am not sure really adding key fixed my problem